# Set transformation in Qfield

Tags: qfield, ntv2-transformation

I am wondering if it is possible to set a custom transformation in Qfield. We are doing surveing in austria and unfortunately the most common Coordinate-System is not ETRS89 based.

In QGIS it is possible to copy a NTV2-Grid into the \proj folder and to select this as the standard transformation. Is this also possible in Qfield?

I have seen that with the latest version it is possible to select a grid for vertical shift. It would be great if this is also possible for horizontal coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

For https://inputapp.io (which is also based on QGIS) you can copy the proj folder under your project (only once) and after the project gets transferred to the device, the transformation gets registered.